# How do I make a word repeat?

Tags: java

How would I make a word repeat three times in java with a return statement. I want it to look like "wordwordword". Also how would I make a second separate method so that each letter gets repeated 3 times? so that it looks like "wwwooorrrddd" Here is what I have so far (I need to use a return statement as well).

```
public static String repeatText(String text) {
 String repeat;
 repeat = text;
 return repeat + repeat + repeat;
}
```

Comment: That code looks fine for repeating a word; is it not working?

Comment: What is your problem with this snippet?

Comment: @Mauren It doesn't do "wwwooorrrddd" :)

Comment: Hint: use a *loop* over the *characters* in `text`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about "for" loops...

Comment: Other things that you may find useful: String has a "length()" method and a "charAt(int index)" method. Bonus points: It also has a "toCharArray()" method that returns a char[].

Comment: I suggest you reading [these contents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: I can do it without a loop.  But best to let him learn to walk before we show him how to fly.

Comment: It is not working, it is only repeating the word once rather than the three times I want

Comment: @user3290671 The code you've posted should work fine.  If it's only repeating the word once, the problem is probably with the code that calls `repeatText` and outputs the result, rather than with `repeatText`.  We may need to see that.

Comment: repeat = repeatLetters(text);
   System.out.println(text + " repeated 3 times is " + repeat);

Comment: Is what I had before it to call the method

Comment: umm, we can't help you with `repeatLetters` unless we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(repeatText("bar"));
    System.out.println(changeText("bar"));
}

public static String repeatText(String text)
{
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        temp += text;

    return temp;
}

static String changeText(String text)
{
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++)
            temp += text.substring(i, i + 1);

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
public static String repeatText(String text,
    int count) {
  // return text + text + text;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append(text);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static String repeatLetters(String text,
    int count) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      sb.append(c);
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(repeatText("word", 3));
  System.out.println(repeatLetters("word", 3));
}
```

Which prints

```
wordwordword
wwwooorrrddd
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided works fine; the problem is most likely with how you're dealing with the return value. Java is not pass by reference so the String you pass in will not change

(ex.)

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     String text = "word";
     String newText = "";
     repeatText(text); // this is probably how you're calling it which is why it's not working
     newText = repeatText(text); // this is how you should be calling it retain the value;
 }
```

As far as making the other method I would suggest looking at the Java docs for the String object and for loop.

String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

For loop: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html